# breaking a loop called inside the slot of a QObject living in a thread

Tags: qt

AcquisitionManager is a QObject living in a thread, I use it to acquire samples from an acquisition PCI-Express card :

```
m_acquisitionThread = new QThread(this);
m_acquisitionManager = new AcquisitionManager();

m_acquisitionManager->moveToThread(m_acquisitionThread);
m_acquisitionThread->start();
```

In my application code (living in the main thread), I use this :

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_acquisitionManager, "executeDataAcquisition", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

to launch data acquisitions.

Inside 'executeDataAcquisition' slot, I have a loop :

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; ++i)
{
    // blocking calls...
}
```

Sometimes, I want the user to abort acquisitions ASAP, I thought about using a boolean variable (+ volatile) that I modify from the main thread. Even if this isn't very thread safe, the boolean variable is only read by the 'slave' thread and only written by the master thread (main) :

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfLoops && m_bKeepAcquiring; ++i)
{
    // blocking calls...
}
```

Is it right to do so ? I saw this technique in a lot of software I worked on but I don't know if it's safe to do so. Is there another technique ?

Comment: Off topic but... since you mention the keyword [`volatile`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) you should note that it has nothing to do with -- and has no benefits regarding -- synchronization *between* threads.  An [`std::atomic<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with "even if this isn't very thread safe" this becomes a bit of a code style question really.  I mean if you don't care about direct cross-thread access then I guess it doesn't matter.

Personally I probably would not do it that way. It's pretty simple to add a method to the worker thread to set the "stop" flag (and even protect the flag with a simple mutex like `QReadWriteLock`). Then the stop can be ordered "properly" with a signal or queued meta method invocation. If the flag isn't likely to be set from anywhere except a main controller thread, skipping a mutex might be fine, though it's also fairly cheap insurance.

```cpp
class AcquisitionManager ... {

public slots:
  void requestStop() {
    QWriteLocker lock(&m_flagMutex);
    m_bStopRequested = true;
  }

  void executeDataAcquisition() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfLoops && !stopRequested(); ++i) {
      // blocking calls...
      QCoreApplication::processEvents();  // gives a chance for queued requestStop() call to be invoked
    }
  }

private:
  inline bool stopRequested() {
    QReadLocker lock(&m_flagMutex);
    return m_bStopRequested;
  }

  bool m_bStopRequested = false;
  QReadWriteLock m_flagMutex;

};
```

Comment: if I send a signal from main thread to the slot "requestStop", it will not be executed until executeDataAcquisition has finished its execution, isn't it ? so requestStop doesn't need to be a slot right ? just a public method. Are slots, of objects living in a different thread, called using MetaObject::invokeMethod or via signals always executed asynchronously ? I mean do I need to simply call the slot like a normal method to execute it synchronously or is it also possible with invokeMethod ?

Comment: @Aminos You either `QObject::connect()` a signal from your controller to the worker `requestStop()` slot (and then use `emit theSignal()` in the controller to trigger it), or you can do it with the queued meta method invocation from the controller, like you do for starting the worker. `connect()` has an optional connection type param (`Qt::DirectConnection/QueuedConnection`). For cross-threaded communication you'd choose "Queued" just like the meta method invoke. Usually "Queued" is chosen automatically when Qt detects the objects live in different threads, but it doesn't hurt to be specific..

Comment: @Aminos I guess the quicker way would be to say do not call methods in different threads directly. Also to answer your question, when you send a signal from controller, the worker will receive it as soon as it has "time," which presumably would be at the top of the loop in the example, after the "blocking calls.". OTOH if you try to call `requestStop()` directly from controller (no signal/queued invoke) then the calling thread is going to have to wait until the worker is "free" before it can return from the call (GUI lag/etc).

Comment: The `QThread` docs and also [Synchronizing Threads](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html) have some useful points if you haven't read those completely yet.

Comment: I forgot that there is a method that I can call before the end of loop to process received signals (process event loop or something like that).

Comment: @Aminos Ah I totally forgot about that also, sorry. Yes, in a tight loop it's good to call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` at the bottom before it goes to check for the stop request. This gives the queued invocations a chance to fire. I added the line to my example.

Comment: I found an old and reliable application where I already done this : in the condition of the loop I called a method named isCanceled inside it, I called QThread::currentThread()->eventDispatcher(); to get the event dispatcher, then on this last I called processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);